# Mathematica v12 Integration bug?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, symbolic

**Bug introduced in 12.0 and fixed in 12.1**

---

After upgrading to mathematica 12, this integral gives the wrong result, also with other types of similar integrals.

```
Integrate[t[2]*Exp[t[2]],t[2]]
```

The output

```
Exp[t[2]^2]/2
```

is wrong (it should be `E^t[2] (-1 + t[2])`).  Such problem does not exist in previous versions.

PS, I have to use a lot of `t[i]` in my program, even if I change the `[i]` to subscripts, the problem is still there.

Comment: It is interesting to note that if I pick a variable without index, then it gives you what you expect.  In other words, Integrate[blah*Exp[blah], blah] gives (-1 + blah) E^blah as you expect.  OK, a new wrinkle:  when using the t[2], I notice that it doesn't properly highlight the variables over which we are integrating.

Comment: `Integrate[t[1] Sin[t[1]], t[1]]` fails, but `Integrate[t@Hold[2]*Exp[t@Hold[2]], t@Hold[2]]` succeeds.

Comment: Please report the issue to the support.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fixed in 12.1

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

```
ClearAll[t];
Integrate[t[2]*Exp[t[2]], t[2]]
```